# Zend debugger in Eclipse on OS X 10.7

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-debugger

I am trying to get Zend Debugger working in Eclipse.

OS X 10.7
MAMP 2.0.5 using php 5.3.6, port 8888
- phpinfo says I have Zend_Debugger configured
- allowed hosts is 127.0.0.1/32
Eclipse Helios
- Zend is default debugger

When I try to test the debugger in Debug Configurations, I get a timeout error.
When I try and actually debug a page, the page loads without breaking to debug (i.e., it actually finds the server and files).

Suggestions?